# Cannot access non-static method in TAP over APM extension

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm new to this and I am trying to create a TAP-over-APM wrapper for the BeginConnect method for my Socket object

```
public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint endpoint)
{
    return TaskFactory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, endpoint, null);
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `FromAsync` method "Cannot access non-static method `FromAsync`" in static context.

How should my code be like?

Comment: FromAsync needs to be static.

Comment: @Sam: That's a BCL method.

Comment: @SLaks see my answer below than create an instance of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need an instance of `TaskFactory`.

You can use the default singleton instance (`Task.Factory`), or you can create your own using one of its constructors.

Answer (score -1):

You can call `static` methods inside `none static` methods but you cannot call non static method inside a static method.

So either change the `FromAsync` to be static or create an instance of it.

Comment: You can't change a BCL method. And saying that you can't call non-static methods from static methods is quite misleading.

Comment: @svick if you read properly I have also said "create an instance of it"